# Ошибка в Gulp помогите пожалуйста исправить!

Tags: gulp

[![Ошибка в Gulp][1]][1]

Работал над сайтом, но gulp самостоятельно завершил работу, после этого при новом запуске выходит вот такой код.

```
[20:54:59] Using gulpfile ~\html\html\gulpfile.js
[20:54:59] Starting 'styles'...
[20:54:59] Starting 'scripts'...
[20:54:59] Starting 'watch'...
[20:54:59] Finished 'watch' after 67 ms
[20:55:02] Finished 'scripts' after 3.23 s
```

Помогите решить проблему, буду очень благодарен! Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как минимум нужен ваш gulpfile.js чтобы понять что вы там делаете

Comment: Верните текст, который был до скриншота.

Comment: Добавил, буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Простите Вы имели в виду так, подскажите